# Suggest me gaming phone with LCD display without notch and rounded corners

Tags: smartphones

Suggest me gaming phone with LCD display without notch and rounded corners. With custom ROMs available and dual sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are opting for a gaming phone here are some recommendations:

1. Asus ROG Phone II(Recommended)
2. RAZER PHONE 2
3. Apple iPhone XR
4. OnePlus 7T
5. OnePlus 7 Pro
6. XIAOMI BLACK SHARK 2
7. Samsung Galaxy S10 Lite
8. Nubia Red Magic 3s
   ....
   ....

And many more!!

Comment: May I ask you your budget?

Comment: Price doesn't matter, I don't like iPhones. Actually only RAZER PHONE 2 fits all requirements I mentioned in my question.